# User can write, but not application

Tags: windows-7

Using Windows 7 64-bit I have a 32-bit program that's supposed to place a configuration file in:

```
c:\ProgramData\Company\Application\
```

But for some reason it fails nine times out of ten.

However, the user that is running the program is not admin nor have they any problems manually creating files in that directory.

What would be different for a program automatically trying to create a file there compared to a user saving a text file there with Notepad?

The application manifest is currently 'asInvoker' and we are only seeing this on some of the Windows 7 machines.

Comment: Let me guess: it's a 64-bit machine, the program is not running as administrator, and the program is 32-bit. If so, I know what's going on. Either way, please reply @BenN to tell the details.

Comment: @BenN Sounds interesting. It's a 32-bit program and it's running as the current user and not elevated. Although the user is a local admin on the machine in question.Not entirely sure about OS architecture to be honest, but it being 64-bit is not totally unlikely.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/384116/2013

Comment: @Nifle Maybe I'm wrong, but doesn't that only apply to the 'Program Files' directory? Problem here is writing a settings file in a sub-directory under 'ProgramData'.

Comment: You are correct - Voting to reopen

Comment: Thanks @Nifle. I've tried to add some more information as well. But I'm new to this format so I'm not sure what can be useful.

Comment: I would suspect the "virtualization" that 32-bit programs are subjected to. See this: https://www.curlybrace.com/words/2010/09/09/windows-vista7-file-system-virtualization/