# Why does Windows 7 bizarrely present two different versions of the same file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vim, filesystems, notepad

I've stumbled across what I consider to be some very bizarre behaviour by Windows 7 (it may apply to later versions of Windows too but I'm testing on Win7) for files in certain locations and I can't seem to find any information about it on Google, so I was wondering whether someone who knows about Windows internals could explain this to me.

So basically, this behaviour exhibits itself for files in certain directories.  I'm not sure which ones exactly but it seems to include some directories in `Program Files (x86)`; for the purposes of my testing I used the install directory for Europa Universalis 3, which is `Program Files (x86)\Paradox Interactive\Europa Universalis III`.

This behaviour applies to files already in the directory, but to produce a clean reproducible demonstration I started by creating a file `text.txt` on the desktop.  The file contained the text:

```
Hello world!
```

I like to use EditPad Lite 5.4.0 for my main text editor (yeah I know it's old but I've gotten used to it) but I also have Vim for Windows 8.0.586 installed.  When I open the file in either, I see the same text, and when I edit the text in either, both programs see the same edited text.  So far, so good.

I copy the file into `Program Files (x86)\Paradox Interactive\Europa Universalis III`, and get a prompt for admin access to be able to copy the file, which I allow.  This is where the weirdness begins.  I open that copied file in EditPad Lite, add some text, and save (file does not appear as read-only):

```
Hello world!
Edited with EditPad Lite.
```

I then open the file with Vim and Vim shows the OLD version of the file:

```
Hello world!
```

I try to edit and save but Vim sees this file as read-only!  So I open with Vim as Administrator, and edit the file and save:

```
Hello world!
Edited with Vim.
```

When I open the file with EditPad Lite again, I see the EditPad version of the file!  So now we have 2 versions of the file which I will term the "EditPad version" and the "Vim version".

**"EditPad" version (IS NOT read-only):**

```
Hello world!
Edited with EditPad Lite.
```

**"Vim" version (IS read-only):**

```
Hello world!
Edited with Vim.
```

Even a reboot doesn't change things, so it doesn't seem to be some sort of Windows memory caching; it's actually persisting these 2 different versions of the file to disk!  Upon further experimentation, I determined that different programs seem to access different versions of the file:

**"Vim" version of the file:**

- Vim 8.0.586
- Vim 8.0.586 as administrator
- 7-Zip 16.04 (64-bit)
- Windows Explorer
- Windows 7 Notepad

**"EditPad" version of the file:**

- EditPad Lite 5.4.0
- Europa Universalis 3
- Windows XP Notepad

What on Earth is Windows 7 doing here?  Why does it present 2 different versions of the file, one being read-only and the other not?  My best guess is that there are two different system calls being used and Windows 7 presents a different version of the file to the different calls, or perhaps 64-bit programs see one version of the file and 32-bit ones see a different version?  Can anyone explain this and is this behaviour documented anywhere?

Comment: Seems related: https://superuser.com/questions/384107/why-cant-i-edit-a-program-files-file-on-windows-7/384116#384116

Comment: LOL thanks, "File and Registry Virtualization" indeed seems to be what is causing this weirdness.  Oh the hacks Microsoft put in place for the sake of backwards compatibility...

Comment: Although there is one thing that isn't explained by this: when I open the file with Vim and I'm *not* running as Administrator, I still see the non-redirected version of the file.  Why is this?  Shouldn't Windows redirect Vim to the non-Administrator version?

Comment: VIM may well be "UAC aware" and as a result not being caught and redirected.

Comment: But it would actually be more useful if it *did* present the redirected version; it would reflect what other applications not running as Administrator would see.

Comment: "Why does it present 2 different versions of the file, one being read-only and the other not?" - You actually have two files in two different locations.  This done silently to the application, because the application cannot modify the file in question, and was a change to how Windows allows an application to do something.  This was done when Vista was released