# File invisible to many software

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, dll

I installed the RSAT tools to try to mange some certificates via the standard CA library certadm.dll.

The dll is showing in C:\Windows\System32 in the windows explorer

[image]

But is invisible in other programs like in everything

[image]

or, more importantly for my use, in Visual Studio 2019 :

[image]

Why is it showing this behavior, and what can I do to make it reapear ?

Comment: Check `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\system32` https://superuser.com/questions/384107/why-cant-i-edit-a-program-files-file-on-windows-7/384116#384116

Comment: no `Windows` folder in AppData\Local\VirtualStore, just a `ProgramData` one with nvidia stuff in it

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, have you ever tried to select the file by copying the file's path, and then appending the file's name?

> eg. pasting this into the "file name" part of the popup asking for file selection: 
>   `C:\Windows\System32\certadm.dll`

Furthermore, I might be very stupid even bothering to suggest this, but have you ever checked while the file was hidden?
File > Properties > Attributes > Hidden

Comment: I tried that but to no avail, it telling me the file cannot be found. I've rechecked the file and it's not hidden, and nothing seem weird in the security tab : the Users group and system have at least read and read&execute