# What are the ways to hide files NOT using commonly known file attributes options in Windows?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I am trying to discover the ways Windows hides files without using the hidden or system attributes.  I have a program that allows me to save print output as a pdf file using the basic Microsoft print to pdf driver.

- The program appears to save the file, but when I go to search for it, the file is not displayed.
- The usual recovery methods of removing file attributes such as running cmd as an administrator or changing folder view options do not work to reveal the file.

How do I know it's there? I repeat the process of printing the file to a pdf to the same folder and it shows up in the print dialog list of files and folders and even asks to replace the file that is already there with the new version when I hit save. What is this program doing to hide this file?

Comment: What exact path do you save the file to?

Comment: The exact path matters here as @KamilMaciorowski states. If you are saving to an operating system protected area then you might find the file is being put into a separate area [that only your user can see in programs that cannot write to protected locations](https://superuser.com/questions/384107/why-cant-i-edit-a-program-files-file-on-windows-7/384116#384116). As a result you will see it in the program you save from, but not Explorer. You should, by preference, write to your own user directories if that is the case.