# Where does wget put downloaded files on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, download, wget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where on my computer did Wget download this image?](https://superuser.com/questions/77279/where-on-my-computer-did-wget-download-this-image)

I am trying to download a file using wget in Windows 7. I used the following command to download the file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>wget http://www.example.com/downloads/sample.mp3
```

It showed details of downloading, like checking connection (which returned 200 OK), then started the download (showed progress of download also) and then finished:

```
Downloaded: 1 files, 2.6M in 15s (178 KB/s)
```

But I could not find the downloaded file. Where did wget put it?

Comment: Related: [Where on my computer did Wget download this image?](http://superuser.com/q/77279/108226)

Comment: Thanks @Indrek, http://superuser.com/questions/77279/where-on-my-computer-did-wget-download-this-image#444390 solved my issue

Comment: Sree, please don't put "solved" in the title. If you solved your problem, you should post an answer below or ask the one who helped solve it to do so. In the case of a duplicate question, we'll just close it as a duplicate so others can find the solution there.